# Use preg_split() or similar to split string in php using leading and trailing ** as a dlimeter

Tags: php, regex

### I have a string:

```
** All quoted material is subject to prior sale **
** All quotes are valid for 30 days **
** No manufacturer's warranty provided unless otherwise specified **
```

I would like to split the string into an array using the leading and trailing `**`'s as delimiters, in some instances there may or may not be a new line separator between each group.

---

This is the regex I have come up with,

```
/(\\*\\*[^\*\*]*\\*\\*)/
```

From my understanding, I am using `**` as the first delimiter, capturing everything that is not `**` and using `**` as the end delimiter.

---

This is my entire function

```
preg_split('/(\\*\\*[^\*\*]*\\*\\*)/', $termsNOMaString, NULL, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

The result I am getting is

```
array(
    0: ""
    1: "** All quoted material is subject to prior sale **"
    2: ""
    3: "** All quotes are valid for 30 days **"
    4: ""
    5: "** No manufacturer's warranty provided unless otherwise specified **"
    6: ""
);
```

How can I properly split the sample string using `**` as opening and closing delimiters? Or improve my current method to eliminate the empty array indexes?

Comment: `preg_split()` seems like the wrong tool. `preg_match_all()` would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `preg_split()`, use `preg_match_all().`

```
preg_match_all('/\*\*(.*?)\*\*/', $termsNOMaString, $match, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

`$match[0]` will contain the full matches, `$match[1]` contains just the capture group, which is the matches without the surrounding `**`.

BTW, in your code, note that there's no difference between `[^**]` and just `[^*]`. `[]` matches single characters, not sequences, so putting `**` in there doesn't mean that it should skip over `**` but not `*`.

Comment: Thank you for clarity on my regex statement, and explaining the output of `preg_match_all` I can make better use of each statement/line now also.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg_split` like this with a simple regex that matches `**` surrounded by whitespaces:

```
$str = '** All quoted material is subject to prior sale **
** All quotes are valid for 30 days **
** No manufacturer\'s warranty provided unless otherwise specified **';

print_r(preg_split('/\s*\*\*\s*/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
```

[Code Demo](https://ideone.com/s6eaEg)

Here use of flag `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` will remove all empty results from output array.

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => All quoted material is subject to prior sale
    [1] => All quotes are valid for 30 days
    [2] => No manufacturer's warranty provided unless otherwise specified
)
```